# Dropbox API ListFolder limit 2000 entries

Tags: java, dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I found this out recently that the listFolder/Continue API returns 2000 entries only. And I have also tried recursion and while loops to fetch all the metadata and add to a existing top level result.getEntries() list. But none of these approaches are working, I still see that only 2000 metadata entries are in the ultimate result.

Has anyone tried and made it work in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each page of `listFolder` results, i.e., each response from a single call to `listFolder` or `listFolderContinue`, can contain up to about 2,000 entries. (Note that this number is not guaranteed, so you should not rely on it.)

To make sure you can get all of the items in a folder, you need to use both `listFolder` and `listFolderContinue`, calling back to `listFolderContinue` with the latest `cursor` when the `hasMore` on the last call was `true`. There's a working example here:

https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/c6aeb4bf3011e6b803eaa325ea20a52f8412ee0f/examples/tutorial/src/main/java/com/dropbox/core/examples/tutorial/Main.java#L32

Comment: I saw the example quoted here, but how will that combine all the metadata in a single list?

Comment: The sample just prints to system out, but you can aggregate the results in whatever variable/data structure makes sense for your app.

Comment: In my case, I get 3, 15, 19, 20, 55, 106 and 21 results from each of those (continued) requests, without setting a custom `limit`. Is there a reason for these result set chunks to be so (seemingly) randomly sized?

Comment: @phil294 There are a number of different factors that will affect how many results may be returned per page, such as file count, account activity, server availability, etc., which can vary over time.